# SQL select data from multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm creating an e-commerce store with SQL database set up with a shopping cart. Ive managed to get the shopping cart to work and a few tables set up in database. I'm now having problems with products with different sizes, for e.g. Shirt will have 3 different sizes, each size will also have a different price.

Here are how my tables are set up:

```
CREATE TABLE products(
        id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        product_name varchar(255) NOT NULL,
        price varchar(16) NOT NULL,
        details text NOT NULL,
        category varchar(16) NOT NULL,
        subcategory varchar(16) NOT NULL,
        date_added date NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        UNIQUE KEY product_name (product_name)
        )

CREATE TABLE admin(
        id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
        username varchar(24) NOT NULL,
        password varchar(24) NOT NULL,
        last_log_date date NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY(id),
        UNIQUE KEY username (username)
        )

CREATE TABLE sizes(
                  SizeID int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                  id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
                  Size varchar(24) NOT NULL,
                  Price varchar(6) NOT NULL,
                  PRIMARY KEY(sizeID),
          UNIQUE KEY ID (ID)

)
```

I can grab the information from products table, name, price, category etc but how would I select the information from sizes table as well as the products table. This information must match so tables have to be linked by FK?

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $id = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#i', '', $_GET["id"]);
    //use this var to check to see if this ID exists, if yes then get the product
    //details, if no then ecit this script and give message why
     $sql=mysql_query("SELECT*FROM products WHERE id='$id' LIMIT 1");
     $productCount=mysql_num_rows($sql);//count number of rows in sql variable
     if($productCount>0){
         //get all product details
         while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql)){

         $id=$row["id"];
         $product_name=$row["product_name"];
         $price=$row["price"];
         $details=$row["details"];
         $category=$row["category"];
         $subcategory=$row["subcategory"];
         $date_added = strftime("%b %d %Y",strtotime($row["date_added"]));
         //product_name, price, details, category, subcategory, date_added
         }
     }else{
           echo "This item does not exist.";
           exit();
         }
}else{
    echo "Data to render this page is missing.";
    exit();
}
```

This grabs data from products table but i still need size and price from the sizes table, and they need to match the item id. How would i go about doing this?

Comment: The answer to, "This information must match so tables have to be linked by FK?", is yes.

Comment: I would recommend looking into PDO (http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and prepared statements especially for doing a e-commerce site.

Comment: You can't have 2 autoincrement columns in one table.

Answer (score 2):

From a database design point of view, you might want a many to many relationship between sizes and products.  And, if the size affects the price, you'll want to store the price in the many to many table.

Also, store the price as a number, not a varchar.  You might want to do math with it.

Comment: I orginally stored as varchar instead of int just so I could use decimal values, storing as a number would make more sense i guess

Comment: Not all numbers are integers.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should have one more table (product_sizes for example):

```
CREATE TABLE product_sizes(
    product_id int(11),
    size_id int(11)
);
```

And this table will connect your products with your sizes.
In this case your query will look like:

```
SELECT p.*, s.Size, s.Price 
FROM products AS p, sizes AS s, product_sizes AS ps
WHERE p.id=ps.product_id AND s.id=ps.size_id
AND .... your additional conditions
```

This is many to many relationship in databases.

Here you can read more info about these relationships: http://sqlrelationship.com/many-to-many-relationship/

Comment: Ahh Feels like I'm at Uni again with this database work, its all coming back to me now, thanks, I'll let you know how it goes.

Comment: It looks like each product (ID) will be mapped to several sizes (SizeID and ID) - a one-to-many relatonship seems reasonable here - if it's clothing for example, you wouldn't map multiple products to the row for large shirt - you'd only match the shirt product.

Comment: the products will be selling will be plant nutrients, each brand will have a different size and price, e.g l litre cost £25, 5 litre cost £50,. would a one-to-many relationship here be reasonable?

Comment: It is your choice. One to many is when you want to duplicate some of Sizes in second table

Answer (score -2):

select a.name, a.price, a.category, b.price, b.size
from products a, sizes b
where a.id = b.id

so you'd set $sql to this query

Comment: There is no relationship between the products and sizes table.

Comment: my mistake - I saw id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment n both table definitions and assumed that it was the relationship

Comment: I have fixed this now so there is relationship between products and sizes table.

Comment: You can't join directly 2 tables when you need many to many relationships.